# How to get the total number of pages in MPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using PHP MPDF to create PDF files. At the footer I'm able to print the current page number using

```
{PAGENO}
```

But how do I get the total number of pages in the PDF file? So that in the footer I can print like:

```
Page (Current Page) of (Total number of pages)   
Page 1 of 6
```

Answer (score 30):

According to the [official documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=217):

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->setFooter("Page {PAGENO} of {nb}");
```

Comment: Here is a working link to all [replaceable aliases](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/replaceable-aliases.html).

Answer (score 9):

you can use **{nb}** it gives you total number of pages in mpdf

Comment: can we get total number of pages using {nb} in pdf body instead of header/footer? i need to display total pages count in pdf content.

Comment: @ÛmÄîrMÄlîk You got anything for this mate?

Comment: @DeepakSingh looks like `{nb}` was replaced in the pdf bode before mPDF 6.0, but now it only works in header/footer. See [the documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/replaceable-aliases.html) for details.

Comment: @ÛmÄîr-MÄlîk
 it works great in mpdf 7.x with simply {nb} in html page I use for header of page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my html header template :

```
{PAGENO}/{nb}
```

For example,on 1st of total of 3 pages, the result will be :

*1/3*

So, you can write it wherever you want in your HTML code like header, footer, body...