# MPDF Total Page Issues

Tags: php, mpdf, page-numbering

MPDF How to pass the total of page number to PHP variable?

Or how to set page number start at 0.

Mpdf version 7.

Thanks

Comment: seems to be duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083746/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-pages-in-mpdf
Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of pages to a variable, you can use

```
$pageCount = count($mpdf->pages);
```

This is however undocumented and can stop working in future versions.

As noted in the [documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html),

> the page numbering can be reset to any positive number.

As 0 is not positive, it is not possible to start page numbering with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, its according to the official documentation:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->setFooter("Page {PAGENO} of {nb}");
```

I means `PAGENO` is return current page and `nb` is total numbers of pages